# create recursive snapshots with BTRFS

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, btrfs

I'm working on a shell script (just with btrfs default tools), which should do recursive snapshots of all subvolumes. My BTRFS looks like that and each directory is a subvolume. In the `.snapshots` directory are the snaps stored from the parent directory.

```
── .snapshots
├── sub1
│   ├── .snapshot
│   └── subsub1
│       └── .snapshot
├── sub2
│   ├── .snapshot
│   └── subsub2
│       └── .snapshot
└── sub3
    ├── .snapshot
    └── subsub3
        └── .snapshot
```

**My problem**

Imagine, there was a file added in subsub3 and you want to create a new snapshot from the whole BTRFS root and save it in `.snapshots`, then I see empty files and only from the direct childs. That means there is no directory `sub3/subsub3` in the `.snapshots` directory.

With `sudo -n btrfs subvolume list /path` I can see all subvolumes and it's possible to filter with `awk '{print $2}'` all IDs, but what's the best way for recursion?

Can you give me a hint?

The result should be similar like `zfs -r`, but without using ZFS.